# Only Show Data For Min(woID)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

With my data I am only wanting to show the `SUM(ISNULL(dolamt,0))` for the `MIN(woID)` - however my query shows the `SUM(ISNULL(dolamt,0))` for every row.  Below is sample DDL -

```
Declare @Info Table
(
    customer varchar(500)
    ,dolamt decimal(10,2)
    ,pddate date
)

Declare @Custs Table
(
    customer varchar(500)
    ,active varchar(10)
)

Declare @WorkOrders Table
(
    customer varchar(500)
    ,woID int
    ,sitename varchar(250)
    ,companycost decimal(10,2)
)

Insert Into @WorkOrders (customer, woID, sitename, companycost) Values
('Customer A', 1, 'Site 1', '10.23'), ('Customer A', 2, 'Site 1', '23.33'),
('Customer A', 3, 'Site 1', '44.12'), ('Customer B', 4, 'Site 2', '44.33'),
('Customer B', 5, 'Site 2', '12.12'), ('Customer C', 6, 'Site3', '22.11'),
('Customer D', 7, 'Site 4', '22.11'), ('Customer D', 8, 'Site 5', '100.12'),
('Customer D', 9, 'Site 6', '23.14')

INSERT INTO @Custs (customer, active) Values
('Customer A', 'Yes'), ('Customer B', 'Yes')
,('Customer C', 'Yes'), ('Customer D', 'Yes')
,('Customer E', 'No'), ('Customer F', 'No')

Insert Into @Info (customer, dolamt, pddate) Values
('Customer A',  '3286.12',  '7/17/2016')
,('Customer A', '9665', '11/25/2016')
,('Customer A', '154.13',   '6/29/2016')
,('Customer B', '73575.37', '12/30/2016')
,('Customer A', '134491.15',    '9/30/2016')
,('Customer A', '112.5',    '11/30/2016')
,('Customer C', '1140.9',   '8/31/2016')
,('Customer C', '5512', '2/8/2016')
,('Customer C', '82323',    '7/31/2016')
,('Customer C', '450',  '10/23/2016')
,('Customer D', '6050.91',  '3/13/2016')
,('Customer B', '520.84',   '8/19/2016')
,('Customer D', '1554.35',  '8/31/2016')

Select
cs.Customer
,[Work Order ID] = COALESCE(wo.woID,0)
,[Company Cost] = SUM(ISNULL(wo.companycost,0))
,[Total Amt] = COALESCE((Select Top 1 SUM(ISNULL(dolamt,0)) FROM @Info nf WHERE nf.Customer = wo.Customer),0)
FROM @WorkOrders wo
RIGHT JOIN @Custs cs
ON cs.Customer = wo.customer
GROUP BY cs.Customer, wo.woID, wo.Customer
ORDER BY cs.Customer ASC
```

Which produces this result set
[image: Current Results]

I want this to be returned result set (only update MIN(woID))
[image: Desired Results]

What do I need to change in my query so that I get the desired result set returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT cs.Customer
    ,[Work Order ID] = COALESCE(wo.woID, 0)
    ,[Company Cost] = SUM(ISNULL(wo.companycost, 0))
    ,[Total Amt] = CASE 
        WHEN wo.woid = (
                SELECT min(woid)
                FROM @WorkOrders
                WHERE customer = cs.customer
                )
            THEN COALESCE((
                        SELECT TOP 1 SUM(ISNULL(dolamt, 0))
                        FROM @Info nf
                        WHERE nf.Customer = wo.Customer
                        ), 0)
        ELSE 0
        END
FROM @WorkOrders wo
RIGHT JOIN @Custs cs ON cs.Customer = wo.customer
GROUP BY cs.Customer
    ,wo.woID
    ,wo.Customer
ORDER BY cs.Customer ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative which admittedly has an additional cost of ~0.005 but I find much easier to follow.

```
;WITH i AS 
(
  SELECT Customer, dolamt = SUM(dolamt)
  FROM @info GROUP BY Customer
),
w AS 
(
  SELECT Customer, woID, companycost,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY woID)
  FROM @WorkOrders
)
SELECT c.Customer, 
  [Work Order ID] = COALESCE(w.woID, 0),
  [Company Cost]  = COALESCE(w.companycost,0),
  [Total Amt] = COALESCE(CASE w.rn WHEN 1 THEN i.dolamt END,0)
FROM @Custs AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN w ON c.Customer = w.Customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN i ON c.Customer = i.Customer
ORDER BY c.Customer;
```

Comment: This actually made the query 75 seconds faster.  Took the execution time down from 4 minutes 30 seconds to 3 minutes 15 seconds.

Comment: Then you should pick Aaron's answer as the 'accepted' answer.